# Problema na EditText dentro da ListView

Tags: android, listview, edittext

Olá, estou com problema na edittext dentro da listview, ela não deixa eu digitar e está dando esses erros.

Segue erros abaixo:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Segue meu código:

```
editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setLines(qtdeQuestoes);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
frameLayout.addView(editText);
```

Comment: vc ta pondo o edit text dinamicamente em tempo de execução? ou ele ta no xml ?

Comment: Vinicius, realmente o `ListView` é um componente que tem muitos problemas, não vale o esforço de usar ele para layouts mais complexos. Recomendo fortemente que utilize o `RecyclerView` para esse tipo de situação. Na minha opinião o `ListView` só tem utilidade para layouts muito simples.

Comment: Eu estou criando dinamicamente. Então Wakin é q o projeto já está muito grande, será que não tem nada msm q resolva esse problema? desde já agradeço.

Comment: Vinicius, também já tive exatamente a mesma dificuldade com ListView e EditText. A solução que usei foi trocar para RecyclerView, essa que sugiro a você. Acredito que valerá a pena o esforço de implementar RecyclerView no seu projeto

Comment: Eu nunca utilizei RecyclerView, requer muitas mudanças?

Comment: Vinicius, acredito que não, o `Adapter` do `RecyclerView` é uma evolução do `Adapter` do `ListView`, com algumas ressalvas: você é obrigado a implementar o padrão `ViewHolder` (o que é bom) e o `RecyclerView` não trata seleção de item (você terá que fazer por fora). Tirando isso, não há muita diferença. Não vou colocar uma resposta de como usar, pois existem várias perguntas aqui no StackOverflow com detalhes.

Comment: Consegui fazer com RecyclerView, deu certo, vlw!